# How do you hide test accounts when they are not endowed?

Tags: testing, genesis

Our chain spec does not endow any of the test accounts yet we are still seeing them shown (with zero balances) in the Polkadot UI. How do we hide them?

[image: test accounts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening on the polkadotJs side, the accounts will appear if the `ChainType` is either Local or Development:

- https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/e1497ec2baf9a4009ce658e968406d312a604c83/packages/react-api/src/Api.tsx#L188

So try to create a staging or live chain spec.